# How to use an ampersand sign in a build event?

Tags: delphi, powershell, delphi-xe2, build-events

I'm trying to figure out how to call a PowerShell script with spaces in the filename as a Delphi build event.

From CMD I have to call `powershell.exe -Command "& 'Filename With Spaces.ps1'"` which works fine.

Delphi on the other hand doubles the ampersand sign and is trying to turn the command into two commands.

I have tried to set this as the build event:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& '$(PROJECTDIR)\Prebuild.ps1' $(PROJECTDIR)"
```

What gets executed by MSBuild is:

```
powershell.exe -Command "&& 'D:\SVN\AccuLib 3.0\VCLUI\Prebuild.ps1' D:\SVN\AccuLib 3.0\VCLUI"
```

So what does it take to call a `ps1` file containing spaces from a Delphi build event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the File parameter instead, it doesnt require an ampersand:

```
powershell.exe -File "Filename With Spaces.ps1"
```

Comment: Works fine, I can also pass additional arguments to the `ps1` script.

Answer (score 1):

To use an ampersand sign you can create an intermediate `cmd` script.

Delphi build event:

```
Prebuild.cmd "$(PROJECTDIR)"
```

Prebuild.cmd file:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& 'Filename With Spaces.ps1'"
```